# Disallow serialization, allow deserialization on property

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a very simple C# class:

```
[Serializable]
[JsonObject]
public class ObjectBase {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

The properties `Id`, `CreatedDate` and `LastModifiedDate` are values that I don't want to be serialized (I'm integrating with a third party API, and those values can never be updated).

However, I would like those properties to be populated with data when I have JSON that I'm deserializing.

I tried using `[JsonIgnore]`, but that results in the property being skipped during deserialization.  Is it possible to use the properties in this manner?

**Edit**:

I am using inheritance already as all of my objects require the same base properties.  I *always* de/serialize into the child class (e.g. `Account`):

```
[Serializable]
[JsonObject]
public class Account : ObjectBase {
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

As an example, I might have an instance of the `Account` object and the `Id` and `CreatedDate` properties could have a value.  When I serialize that object into JSON, I don't want those properties to be included.  However, when I have JSON and am deserializing, I want those properties to get a value.

Comment: Create a subset class that you serialize, and inherit it for your deserialization class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to exclude certain properties from serialization without having to modify your class structure is to create a custom `ContractResolver` like this:

```
class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> props = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        if (typeof(ObjectBase).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            string[] excludeThese = new string[] { "Id", "CreatedDate", "LastModifiedDate" };
            props = props.Where(p => !excludeThese.Contains(p.PropertyName)).ToList();
        }
        return props;
    }
}
```

When you serialize, just add the resolver to the serializer settings:

```
Account account = new Account
{
    Id = "100",
    CreatedById = "2",
    CreatedDate = new DateTime(2014, 3, 12, 14, 52, 18, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    LastModifiedById = "3",
    LastModifiedDate = new DateTime(2014, 3, 17, 16, 3, 34, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    AccountNumber = "1234567",
    ParentId = "99"
};

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(),
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, settings);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{
  "AccountNumber": "1234567",
  "ParentId": "99",
  "CreatedById": "2",
  "LastModifiedById": "3"
}
```

**Another Approach**

If you don't like the resolver approach, another alternative is to add boolean `ShouldSerializeX` methods to your class where `X` is replaced with names of the properties that you want to exclude:

```
[Serializable]
[JsonObject]
public class ObjectBase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeId()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeCreatedDate()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeLastModifiedDate()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, good suggestion! Unless I'm mistaken, from the one test that I ran the `ShouldSerializeX` approach didn't work for deserialization.

Comment: That is correct, `ShouldSerialize` only works for serialization, it is ignored for deserialization.  That is what you wanted, isn't it?

Comment: What I meant to say was that by introducing the `ShouldSerialize` methods I didn't think deserialization would work (i.e. I wouldn't get a value in the `Id` property and so on).  Perhaps I made a mistake in my test and it actually does work; I'll test that out in the future.  The custom resolver is working perfectly!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Object inheritance is the key. You want to serialize a subset of properties/fields, and deserialize the full set. So, make the full set derive from the subset and use them appropriately in your serialization and deserialization.

Serialize this class:

```
[Serializable]
[JsonObject]
public class ObjectBase
{
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public string LastModifiedById { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize this class:

```
[Serializable]
[JsonObject]
public class ObjectDeserializationBase : ObjectBase
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply David.  I updated my post to show how I am already using inheritance which I think may make this approach tricky.